# Flex - Step Wizard with 8 buttons in header on click of button need to high light the button

Tags: apache-flex, button, coding-style

I used set focus method with focuswidth style property but if you set that then tab order for form in that step do not work as focus is set on that step button

How to highlight button without setting focus on that button ?

I tried for this in component which extends mx:button

UI IMAGE >> https://picasaweb.google.com/117672211821251548555/February12012?authuser=0&feat=directlink#5704169045108382770

Pseudo Code

```
class StepButton extends Button{
    {

    init(){
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showFocus);
    }


    private function showFocus(e:MouseEvent):void{              
                        this.invalidateDisplayList
                        this.setStyle("borderColor", "green");
                        this.setStyle("borderStyle", "solid");
                        this.setStyle("borderThickness", "10" );

    }


                    }
                }

    }


    }
```

Comment: Please help me this has made my life hell :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create this >>

Custom component >> Vbox >> mx:Button

on select on button reset style for all others and change for clicked one .
I used event for this which send to container which hold all these buttons in hbox .

custom button has two methods selectButton and deSelectButton

---

StepButton.mxml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="500" height="100" creationComplete="init()" >


    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="stepchanged", type="com.salpe.ClearOtherSteps")]
    </fx:Metadata>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;


            [Embed(source="bin-debug/assets/images/4.png")]
            [Bindable]
            public var imgCls:Class;

            [Embed(source="bin-debug/assets/images/1.png")]
            [Bindable]
            public var resetcls:Class;



            public function init():void{

                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK ,clicked);
                //addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT ,out);

                setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
            }

            public function clicked(even:MouseEvent):void{

                //Alert.show("Test clcik");
                /* var step:Step = this.parent as Step ;
                step.setStyle("backgroundColor" ,0xFF0000);
                step.invalidateDisplayList(); */

             var evt :ClearOtherSteps = new ClearOtherSteps(ClearOtherSteps.STEP_CHANGE);            
             evt.step = this;            
             trace("StepButton.clicked(even)");


             this.dispatchEvent(evt);


            }


            public function selectButton():void{
                var step:Step = this.parent as Step ;
                step.setStyle("backgroundColor" ,0xFF0000);
                step.invalidateDisplayList();
            }

            public function deSelectButton():void{

                var step:Step = this.parent as Step ;
                step.setStyle("backgroundColor" ,0xFFFFFF);
                step.invalidateDisplayList();
            }

    /*      public function out(even:FocusEvent){

                if(even.relatedObject is StepButton){

                    var other :StepButton = even.relatedObject as StepButton;

                    other.setStyle("backgroundColor" ,0xFFFFFF);
                    other.invalidateDisplayList();



                }
            } */

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    </mx:Button>
```

---

Step.mxml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           xmlns:salpe="com.salpe.*" paddingTop="1" paddingBottom="1" paddingRight="1" paddingLeft="1" mouseChildren="true" creationComplete="init()" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <fx:Style>
        .multipleImageButtonStyle
        {

            upSkin: Embed("bin-debug/assets/images/1.png");
            downSkin: Embed("bin-debug/assets/images/1.png");
            overSkin: Embed("bin-debug/assets/images/1.png");
            ;

        }


    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

     public function init(){
         setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");


     }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <salpe:StepButton id="stepBtn" label="Button Test" height="20" width="100"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true"   />
</mx:VBox>
```

---

TestComponet.mxml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HDividedBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                width="120%" height="120%" creationComplete="init()" xmlns:salpe="com.salpe.*">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Label;



            public function init():void{

                this.addEventListener(ClearOtherSteps.STEP_CHANGE,check);

            }


            public function check(evt:ClearOtherSteps){
                trace("In listner ");
                //Alert.show("Test check");
                var arr:Array = bx.getChildren()
                for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
                {
                    var step:Step = arr[i] as Step;



                    step.stepBtn.deSelectButton();


                }

                evt.step.selectButton();

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:List id="menu" width="20%" height="120%" change="{changeEvt(event)}" dataProvider="{list}" labelField="label">
    </mx:List>  
    <mx:VBox id="content" width="80%" height="120%" backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"> 
        <mx:HBox id="bx" width="120%" height="120%" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto">
        <salpe:Step id= "test1" label="Button Test" height="30" width="120"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true"  color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <salpe:Step  id= "test2"  label="Button Test" height="30" width="120"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true" color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <salpe:Step id= "test3"    label="Button Test" height="30" width="120"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true" color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <salpe:Step id= "test4"  label="Button Test" height="30" width="120"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true" color="0xFFFFFF" />
        <salpe:Step id= "test5"   label="Button Test" height="30" width="120"  styleName="multipleImageButtonStyle" buttonMode="true" color="0xFFFFFF" />
            </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>  
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

---

ClearOtherSteps.as

---

```
package com.salpe
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ClearOtherSteps extends Event
    {
        // Define static constant.
        public static const STEP_CHANGE:String = "stepchanged";

        public var step:StepButton;

        public function ClearOtherSteps(type:String){

            super(type,true, false);
        }


        override public function clone():Event {
            return new ClearOtherSteps(type);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wizard look like this 

https://picasaweb.google.com/115165798993234087290/2February2012?authuser=0&feat=directlink#5704253412621000034